# How do I add a const char * array item to a const char * string?

Tags: c++, arrays, imgui

I am using ImGui and am trying to add an array item to my const char * so that I can display the chosen item. How do I do it? It shows random letters and not what I want.

```
static const char* FruitsList[] = { "Mango", "Apple", "Pear", "Bannana"};
indexFruit = 2;
const char * chosenFruitText = "Chosen Fruit"  + char(FruitsList[indexFruit]);
ImGui::ListBox(chosenFruitText , &indexFruit , FruitsList, IM_ARRAYSIZE(FruitsList));
```

Comment: You can't. `const` means you can't change it. You can allocate yourself a new array that's big enough and writable and write the two strings into it, but that's for madmen and masochists. Use `std::string` instead. Use `std::string::c_str` to get a `const char *` out of the `std::string` for use by the call to `ListBox`.

Comment: You are trying to add two const char*  to each other which is not valid in C++.   At least one side of the addition has to be something that supports string concatenation via this operator.  Like `std::string`.  You need a decent introductory text on the language.

Comment: Sanity check: I assume that, because ImGui is (by the very name) immediate, it doesn't matter that the string will shortly be destroyed. In general you need to be very careful about the result of `.c_str()` not outliving the object it came from.

Comment: `const char * chosenFruitText = "Chosen Fruit"  + char(FruitsList[indexFruit]);` is sneaky . `"Chosen Fruit"` is `const` array of `char`. `char(FruitsList[indexFruit])` takes `FruitsList[indexFruit]`, an address and turns it into a `char`, throwing out most of the address. What you get is a character that might as well be random. Adding a `char` to an array doesn't append the character, it takes the numerical value of the character and uses like an index into the array, performing pointer arithmetic.  That leaves `chosenFruitText` pointing at somewhere after the start of `"Chosen Fruit"`.

Comment: This is all legal C++ syntax so it compiles and probably won't even give you much in the way of compiler warnings. Probably all you'll get is a warning about  `char(FruitsList[indexFruit])` losing precision chopping an address down to one byte.

Answer (score 1):

You can't append a `char`/`const char*` to a `const char[]` (your string literal).  But you can concatenate a `std::string` and a string literal, eg:

```cpp
static const std::string FruitsList[] = { "Mango", "Apple", "Pear", "Bannana"};
indexFruit = 2;
std::string chosenFruitText = "Chosen Fruit" + FruitsList[indexFruit];
ImGui::ListBox(chosenFruitText.c_str(), &indexFruit, FruitsList, IM_ARRAYSIZE(FruitsList));
```

Otherwise, you would have to do something more like this instead:

```cpp
static const char* FruitsList[] = { "Mango", "Apple", "Pear", "Bannana"};
indexFruit = 2;
char chosenFruitText[22] = "Chosen Fruit: ";
strcpy(chosenFruitText+14, FruitsList[indexFruit]);
ImGui::ListBox(chosenFruitText, &indexFruit, FruitsList, IM_ARRAYSIZE(FruitsList));
```

Answer (score 0):

There are no character string operations in the C programming language, not like what your code suggests that you expect. In the expression "const char* ChosenFruit = ...", you are telling the compiler that you want to add the address of the array containing "Chosen Fruit" with the address of the third string in FruitsList (which you truncated to the size of a 'char' because of the typecast), and assign the result to ChosenFruit. ChosenFruit just points to some far away place in memory that most likely does not contain printable characters.

To concatenate two strings in C, you must allocate a new array big enough to hold the result, and copy the characters of the two strings explicitly. You can use the 'strcpy()' and 'strcat()' functions to do the copying:

```
const char* s1 = "Hello ";
const char* s2 = "world!";
char s3[32]; /* big enough to hold s1 and s2 */
strcpy( s3, s1 ); /* copy s1 to s3 */
strcat( s3, s2 ); /* copy s1 to end of s3 */
```

You can do the same in C++, but it is arguably safer and better practice to use 'std::string' objects from the C++ standard library. 'std::string' objects automatically allocate the amount of memory that they need to hold your strings from the heap, automatically free this memory when it is no longer needed, and implement a version of the '+' operator that does what you want (concatenation):

```
#include <string>

static const std::string Fruits[] = { "Mango", "Apple", "Pear", "Banana" };
static const std::string Prefix = "Chosen Fruit ";
std::string ChosenFruit = Prefix + Fruits[index];
```

The expression "ChosenFruit = Prefix + ..." means "call the version of the '+' operator which takes two 'std::string' objects as arguments". This '+' operator concatenates the two strings and returns a new 'std::string' object that contains the result.